# ng-options Key Value pair

Tags: javascript, angularjs

есть массив list объектов вида

```
[
  {Key: "key1", Value: "val1"},
  {Key: "key2", Value: "val2"},
  ...
]
```

при использовании его в операторе ng-repeat

```
<select ng-repeat="obj.Key as obj.Value for obj in list"></select>
```

я в качестве значений опций получаю не свои ключи (key1, key2), а порядковые номера элементов в коллекции. т.е. примерно:

```
<option value='0'>val1</option>
<option value='1'>val2</option>
```

подозреваю,  это связано с именами переменных внутри объектов (Key, Value). Кто-то может разъяснить поподробнее?

UPD: я прошу прощения. в пример кода вкралась ошибка. следует читать ng-repeat как ng-options (в названии запроса указал правильно)...

```
<select ng-options="obj.Key as obj.Value for obj in list" ng-model="selectRes"></select>
```

Comment: Вы неправильно используете ключевое слово `as`

Comment: а как именно стоит его использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить `ng-repeat` с `ng-options`. И добавить `ng-model`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedKey" ng-options="obj.Key as obj.Value for obj in list"></select>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/Lnh7y183/1/)**

Comment: прошу прощения... ваш ответ корректен, но в вопросе была ошибка. возможно вы сможете помочь снова?

Comment: Eсли структура массива `list` именно как в вопросе, то в `ng-model` должно быть значение `obj.Key` а не индекс элемента. Смотрите этот [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnh7y183/2/). Названия `Key` или `Value` тут не мешают. Могу посмотреть что не так если есть возможность воспроизводить проблему в fiddle.